# VBA outlook error when stripping email body

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm using a VBA script to strip the body of an email, i have successfully stripped 90% of the email, but when i get to the final "Enquiry" part i am having an error i cannot fix. This is the email body.

```
Ref: 1993
Business Headline: bla bka
Name: A Name
Email: email@email.com
Tel: 0777777777

Address Line: 123
Address Line 2: someroad
Town: sometown
County: lancashire
Postcode: APOS TCDE

Enquiry:
Please send me more information about this business. Regards, Gary.
```

The problem is at postcode when it is trying to find Enquiry. In my code it seems to find the position of Enquiry but doesnt assign the integer to the variable. Please see screenshots to see what i mean.

[finds correct positon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGxEd.png)

[The variable is just staying at 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0zfr.png)

This is the postcode stripping code :

```
Dim pstcodee As Integer
            pstcodee = InStr(1, b4, "Postcode: ")

        Dim enqui As Integer
            enqui = InStr(1, b4, "Enquiry:")

        Dim pstenquire As String
             pstenquire = Mid(b4, pstcodee, enqui - pstcodee)

        Dim bup2222() As String
        bup2222 = Split(pstenquire, ":")

        postcode = bup2222(1)
```

Comment: The code works OK, and extracts: _" APOS TCDE"_. You have to describe in greater detail what the exact problem is. The screenshots do not show what is the currently executed line (marked in yellow during debugging).

Answer (score 0):

```
postcode = Trim$(Mid$(b4, 8 + Len("Enquiry:" & vbNewLine), Len(b4)))
```